# How can I add a JTable to a JPanel after I have clicked a button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How I can add a JTable to a JPanel after the user has clicked a button? The JLabel is added to the JPanel after the button is clicked but not the JTable.

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ResultSet resultSet = query.getStudentDetails(operateOnSelectedStudent());
            JTable table = null;
            try {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    try {
                        table = new JTable(buildTableModel(resultSet));
                        panel.add(table, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        panel.add(new JLabel("HELLO"));
                        panel.revalidate();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
                        JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);

                        panel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I added the following lines to code to resolve the problem.

```
panel.add(tableContainer);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: The code should be revalidate() then repaint(). The revalidate() invokes the layout manager so the components can have a proper size and location. Usually the panel will then repaint itself, however, the repaint() is added just to make sure the panel repaints itself.

Comment: @camickr I will make the necessary change. Thank you